# What part of the Facebook Graph API should I use to post content with custom actions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to publish similar content to the following snippet from my application:

[image]

The most important tidbits here are the following:

- a photo
- a link
- a text blurb

I'm not entirely sure where in the Graph API it makes sense for me to explore to do this. I'd like for it to show up in people's newsfeed that approve the action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SocialCam example in your picture is using the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/keyconcepts/) part of the Facebook API. Open Graph allows you to define custom [actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/#custom) and custom [objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/) for your app. The idea is to allow the user to express more specific, high-level actions beyond like, comment and share. In your example, "watch" is the Open Graph action, which is a [build-in Action Type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/). [Video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/#video) is the Open Graph object, a [built-in Object Type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/builtin/). Note that "Object" in this context is a type not an instance.

It is possible to define your app's own actions e.g. "review" and link it to custom objects e.g. "Action Movie", "Comedy" etc. You can also define properties for your actions e.g. "Rating" for a review action.

However, if all you require is a "photo, link and a text blurb" you don't have to use the Open Graph but can use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). You can post a link to a video or image by issuing a POST to:

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/feed
```

with params

```
message
name (sender's name)
caption
link (your url)
description
picture (url to picture)
```

where USER_ID is the user who's wall you want to post to.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure they are have set up a a facebook application and defined an [action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-actions/) called "watch" and an [object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-objects/) called "video". they then [publish](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) it by making a post to facebook's graph api.

Facebook walks you through some of the basics while in the management menus, once you've set up a developer account and [created an application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/)

Answer (score 1):

Go through links one by one and having step by step guide from official sources. You will be able to achieve your goal.

1. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/customopengraph/walkthrough/
3. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/objects/